# Lifting maps of classifying bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

In the paper of Okonek and Van de ven "cubic forms and complex 3-folds". In Proposition 8 there is the claim.

Let $M$ be a closed, orientable smooth 6-manifold, and $t_{x}: X \rightarrow BSO(6)$ be the map ascossiated with the tangent bundle (I guess this is refering to the fact that every smooth manifold has a Riemannian metric).

Then, the obstruction to the existance of an almost complex structure lies in $H^{i}(X, \pi_{i-1}(SO(6)/U(3)))$.

Could somebody provide an answer or reference explaining this fact at a reasonably elementary level? (i.e. someone comfortable with most of Hatcher but not a hardcore algebraic topologist)

Comment: A couple things. First, the tangent bundle does not have an oriented orthonormal frame bundle associated to it unless $M$ is orientable; if $M$ is oriented then its oriented orthonormal frame bundle is classified by a map $M \to BSO(6)$. Second, the groups in which your obstructions are not quite right: the obstructions to existence of almost complex structure lie in the groups $H^i(X; \pi_{i-1}(SO(6)/U(3))$.

Comment: Thanks, I am happy to assume my manifold is oriented. I will correct the typo.

Comment: The two relevant points are that different classes of "orientations" on manifolds can be put in correspondence to sections of the classifying map $M \rightarrow BSO(n)$ under $BG \rightarrow BSO(n)$. Homotopy theory has a way of constructing sections which goes by obstruction theory. In the case $G$ is a subgroup of $SO(n)$, the (homotopy) fiber of the map $BG \rightarrow BSO(n)$ is $O(n)/G$ and obstruction theory tells you the obstructions live in the cohomology of $M$ with coefficients in the homotopy groups of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space $BSO(2n)$ is the classifying space for principal $SO(2n)$-bundles. Similarly, the space $BU(n)$ is the classifying space for principal $U(n)$-bundles.

One can take a unitary matrix and write it as a special orthogonal matrix. The complex number $x + iy$ gets sent to the matrix \begin{pmatrix}x 
 & y \\ -y & x\end{pmatrix} and one does this similarly for higher-dimensional matrices. Thus we have a map $U(n) \to SO(2n)$, and by functoriality a map $BU(n) \to BSO(2n)$. By a little bit of work, the (homotopy) fiber of this map is $SO(2n)/U(n)$.

Suppose you have an oriented manifold $M$ of dimension $2n$. Then the oriented orthonormal frame bundle associated to its tangent bundle is a principal $SO(2n)$-bundle, and $M$ admits an almost complex structure if one can reduce the structure group of this bundle to $U(n)$. Put in the language of classifying spaces, this says that one can lift the classifying map $M \to BSO(2n)$ of the oriented orthonormal frame bundle against the map $BU(n) \to BSO(2n)$.

Obstruction theory says that when you want to solve this kind of lifting problem, the obstructions live in cohomology groups of $M$ with coefficients in the (homotopy) fiber of the map you're trying to lift against. The precise groups for this situation are $H^i(M; \pi_{i-1}(SO(2n)/U(n))$.

Maybe this is enough for your situation, but for this specific case it's worth remarking that $\pi_k(SO(2n)/U(n)) \cong \pi_k(SO/U)$ for $k < 2n-1$, where $SO$ and $U$ are the direct limits of $SO(n)$ and $U(n)$ under the usual inclusions $SO(n) \to SO(n+1)$ (and similarly for $U(n)$), respectively. So the coefficient groups for these obstructions live in the stable range except for the very last one that's relevant, $\pi_{2n-1}(SO(2n)/U(n))$. This is nice because the stable groups are either $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, or zero. Also, for these obstructions where the coefficient group works out to $\mathbb{Z}$ the obstruction is actually (up to multiplication by an integer) an integral Stiefel-Whitney class. The first unstable group is not as pretty, but it's either cyclic (sometimes finite, sometimes infinite) or the direct sum $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

**Edit: For the case $n=3$.**
From the above comments, one can compute that $\pi_j(SO/U)$ is zero for $j=0,1,3,4$ and $\pi_2(SO/U) = \mathbb{Z}$ and the first unstable group is $\pi_5(SO(6)/U(3))$, which actually turns out to be zero! Thus an oriented $6$-manifold $M$ admits an almost complex structure if and only if the obstruction in $H^3(M;\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes. This obstruction is, up to multiplication by some integer, the third integral Stiefel-Whitney class, so $M$ admits an almost complex structure if and only if $W_3(M)$ vanishes.

Comment: A small follow-up question. I seem to remember that when doing obstruction theory in fiber bundles, one has to deal with homology with local coefficients (and not just usual homology). Is this correct, or am I mixing something up? If I am not mistaken, how do we know that we can work with a constant local coefficient system here (if we do not assume the manifold to be simply-connected)?

Comment: This is correct. The thing that makes this simpler here is that specifically one of the ingredients in writing down the local system is a homomorphism $\pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(BSO(2n))$. But $\pi_1(BSO(2n)) = \pi_0(SO(2n))$, and $SO(2n)$ is connected. So the local system for this situation turns out to be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer kamills. Just a remark, as Okonek and Van de Ven say, $SO(6)/U(3)$ is diffeomorphic to the manifold $\mathbb{CP}^3$ so using the Hopf fibration d $S^7 \rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^3$ computing their homotopy groups is not an issue.